# Checking if any radio buttons are selected with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to see if any radio buttons are selected using this code:

```
 if (document.getElementById("ra").checked == false && 
 document.getElementById("rb").checked == false  && 
 document.getElementById("rc").checked == false && 
 document.getElementById("rd").checked == false && 
 document.getElementById("re").checked == false ) {

    alert("Please Select An Answer");

}
```

It isn't working and dosen't give the alert, also it doesn't show any errors. Could someone help me with the if statement so I can be sure im doing it correctly, thanks!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The if statement seems correct , can you please provide more code ?

Comment: @Ele you feeling ok? You are coming across as very hostile in this thread, is something bothering you today?

Comment: @Ele as an impartial 3rd party, I think you are coming across a lot more hostile than you might realize. Personally, it feels like you are barking orders and taking shots at people who are trying to help.

Comment: @Ele true as that may be it seems like you might be taking this too personally, maybe just nope out of this thread then and just move on. No sense getting worked up over something you have no control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing innately wrong with the code you posted. My best guess is that you have it in the wrong place. If you just have that block in the outer javascript, it will run when the page is open. You probably want to enclose it in a function that is run when you click a button, submit the form, etc.

Consider the following code:

```js
function check(){

  if (document.getElementById("ra").checked == false && 
     document.getElementById("rb").checked == false  && 
     document.getElementById("rc").checked == false && 
     document.getElementById("rd").checked == false && 
     document.getElementById("re").checked == false ) {

        alert("Please Select An Answer");

    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" id="ra"/>A</li>
<li><input type="radio" id="rb"/>B</li>
<li><input type="radio" id="rc"/>C</li>
<li><input type="radio" id="rd"/>D</li>
<li><input type="radio" id="re"/>E</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Clicking the button does produce the result that I think you are going for.

Comment: How do you dare to post this answer with just a guess??

Comment: @Ele lol what kind of bs is this, that's obviously what the user is asking. Or are you joking???

Comment: @duxfox-- I'm not joking at all.  This answer is a waste of time with no clue about the approach from the OP.

Comment: @Ele I see nothing wrong with trying to provide at least something useful. The OP is clearly new and did not provide enough information, but it is at least likely that what I posted can help them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(document.getElementById("ra").checked == false && document.getElementById("rb").checked == false && document.getElementById("rc").checked == false && document.getElementById("rd").checked == false && document.getElementById("re").checked == false){
    alert("Hello");
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: This is not an answer!

Answer (score -1):

Your code appears to work.  I used it to stub out a simple HTML file and I get an alert when none of the radios are checked and when one is checked (I added an ELSE clause for testing).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" id="ra" name="drone" checked="checked"/> A
<input type="radio" id="rb" name="drone" /> B
<input type="radio" id="rc" name="drone" /> C
<input type="radio" id="rd" name="drone" /> D
<input type="radio" id="re" name="drone" /> E

<script>
 if (document.getElementById("ra").checked == false && 
 document.getElementById("rb").checked == false  && 
 document.getElementById("rc").checked == false && 
 document.getElementById("rd").checked == false && 
 document.getElementById("re").checked == false ) {

    alert("Please Select An Answer");

} else {
    alert("You picked an answer!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe post some example code so we can get a better understanding of where you issue is coming from.